# Update PowerPoint from Excel with 3 decimal points

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I'm creating a VBA code which alters a specific `shapename` at a `shapeslide` and update its value to `shapetext`. These are predefined in Excel starting at the cells `J2,K2,L2`. The values for `shapetext` in Excel is the function `=ROUND(A2+B2,3)`, as I want the PowerPoint to be updated with 3 decimal points. In Excel these values for `shapetext` are shown correctly like, for instance "2,330" (I'm using a Swedish Office package, where "," is the decimal point), but when I update the corresponding value in PowerPoint I get the value "2,33" - the "0" is omitted. If there are no "ending" zero in a number, the PowerPoint gets updated correctly, for instance "0,348" in Excel gives "0,348" in PowerPoint.

```
Set pppres = ppapp.ActivePresentation
r = 2
Do
    shapeslide = Cells(r, 10)
    shapename = Cells(r, 11)
    shapetext = Cells(r, 12)
    pppres.Slides(shapeslide).Shapes(shapename).TextEffect.Text = shapetext
    r = r + 1
Loop Until Cells(r, 10) = ""
```

Is it possible to "force" PowerPoint to show the value with 3 decimals, even if it is an ending zero?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (**Untested**)

```
pppres.Slides(shapeslide).Shapes(shapename).TextEffect.Text = _
Format(val(trim(shapetext)),"0.000")
```

Comment: Thanks for that! When I used `pppres.Slides(shapeslide).Shapes(shapename).TextEffect.Text = _
Format(shapetext,"0.000")` I got the desired results!